# Javascript function for gradual change

Tags: javascript, dom-events, settimeout

I used this [tutorial](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/fadingtext.shtml) to create a basic Javascript function for implementing change during a given period of time.

```
function fadetext(){ 
if(hex>0) {
hex-=11;
document.getElementById("sample").style.color="rgb("+hex+","+hex+","+hex+")";
setTimeout("fadetext()",20); 
}
else
hex=255
}
```

**Question 1:** How to enter variable via `function`; e.g. `fadetext(element, time)`. I was unable to do so by simply replacing the values with variables.

**Question 2:** Is it the standard (and right) method to gradually implement a change by javascript? The confusion point for me is that we use `fadetext()` function inside its own function. Doesn't this make overload?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with a function calling itself.  (although yours does not)

Comment: @SLaks why mine does not? I referenced the tutorial code, which works.

Comment: @Ali: Your function *schedules* itself, it doesn't *call* itself. There is a very important difference.

Comment: @Amadan Now I get the point, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass a function, not a string, to `setTimeout`:

```
function fadeText(element, duration) {
    ...
    setTimeout(function() {
        fadeText(element, duration);
    }, 20);
}
```

This code passes an anonymous function which captures the original parameters in a closure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should set up the timer for `fadetext()` outside the function and define `hex` outside as global variable, so you solve both problems :)
And use `setInterval()` to avoid calling setTimeout every time, and call a function instead of a string.
(As one user pointed out, my code has reusability issues).

```
var hex = 255;
setInterval(fadetext,20);

function fadetext(){ 
   if(hex>0) {
   hex-=11;
   document.getElementById("sample").style.color="rgb("+hex+","+hex+","+hex+")";
   }
}
```

---

As a bonus, you could investigate **jQuery**, fading (and other animated tasks) become really simple to implement, often within a single command or command line.

Comment: No.  Don't pass a string to `setTimeout`.  Also, that's not reusable.

Comment: Damn right, I was editing his code (sloppily). Corrected the string (but I saw many examples using the string, I wonder about cross-browser compatibility now, although passing a function seems to be the most obvious method)

Comment: @SLaks By the way, your solution is very elegant, but does it cause an overhead on function stack calls?

Comment: @Cranio: There is some overhead in creating new anonymous functions, however it's the only way to pass parameters through `setTimeout` (i.e. without using globals, and without using a string parameter). If you meant if it is susceptible to stack overflow (teehee), no, since there's no recursion going on.

Comment: This means that a scheduled function has no memory of its caller, or am I getting the point wrong?

Comment: @Cranio as a matter of fact, I first explored jQuery, but jQuery uses `animate()` function for all fading effects. Thus, the actual code is not simpler than the present one.

Comment: @Cranio: In fact, a scheduled function doesn't *have* a caller. `function showCaller() { console.log(showCaller.caller); } function callShower() { showCaller(); setTimeout(showCaller, 1000); }; callShower();` will print the function `callShower` (in case of calling), followed by `undefined` (in case of scheduling).

Comment: @Amadan: many thanks for the precious insight, upvoting the comment :)

Comment: @Cranio: You're thinking of closures.

Comment: @SLaks: I know the concept of closures well. My doubts were mostly on the domain of callback functions, I wondered if they shared that particular aspects of closures (and they don't as already pointed out).